# Spring: Not display image in thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm doing Spring project use Spring Boot, Spring MVC, Spring Data. Now I have a problem maybe with thymeleaf
 This is my index page
[image]

Logo Bonfire and room picture is image and save in folder `src/main/resource/static/images` in eclipse .

When I use Search function, it will display Search page like this picture

[image]

I don't know why it's not display logo image and room image although I use one template for my index page and search page... And it's still happened with detail page too, images is not displayed. Only index page displayed images

[image]

I think the problem is not by code... I don't know why
This is my `room.html` (index page and search page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="Header :: head">
</head>
<body>
<div th:replace="Header :: header"  class="header"></div>
<div class="container">
        <div class="products">
                <h2 class=" products-in">AVAILABLE ROOM</h2>
                <div class=" top-products">
                 <span th:each="room,iterStat : ${room}">
                    <div class="col-md-3 md-col">
                        <div class="col-md">
                            <a th:href="@{/room/{id}/detail(id=${room.id})}" class="compare-in"><img th:src="@{'images/'+${room.image}}" alt="" />

                            </a>    
                            <div class="top-content">
                                <h5><a th:href="@{/room/{id}/detail(id=${room.id})}"><tr th:text="${room.name}"></a></h5>
                                <div class="white">
                                    <a th:href="@{/room/{id}/book(id=${room.id})}" class="hvr-shutter-in-vertical hvr-shutter-in-vertical2">BOOK</a>
                                    <p class="dollar"><span class="in-dollar">$</span><span>2</span><span>0</span></p>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>                          
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     </span>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
 <div th:replace="Header :: footer"   class="footer"></div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Pleased help me

Comment: Someone can help me T.T

Comment: Try to use `Inspect` function of Chrome browser(or any alternative in other browsers). So, open code of your page, and check paths of your images. Are they right?

Comment: @VadimBeskrovnov I checked paths of my images. I think it right ,you can see index page displayed image, and search page is not athought both of page use one template. I don't know why

Comment: Do you have same image paths in index and search pages?

Comment: @VadimBeskrovnov  index and search pages only use one room.html and i don't change anything..It' not display image in other pages expect index page

Comment: please check whether both index and search pages are in the same root level.

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach to set the image :--

```
<div th:style="'background-image:url('+ ${room.image}+');'"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this.

```
<img th:src="${'images/'+ room.image}" />
```